# I sowed cauliflower but got something different. Which plant is it?

Tags: identification, cauliflower

As you can see on the picture, I am currently sowing cauliflower, but one fellow plant does not look like cauliflower.

[image]

I wonder if it is a cultivated plant at all or am I just taking care of weed here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like *Tagetes* (Marigold), did you have those last year by any chance?

Comment: Could be. But looks pretty much like a flower to me, once you said it. I gonna raise it and keep you updated.